# Patching SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am having the original release of the 2012 server having bulid number 11.0.2100.60. I have a question like can we install the current patches on the existing version or do we need to do it in stages.  For instance, can we install SP4 on the 2012 servers that are on the original release or do we need install an earlier SP first then SP4.

Comment: service pack is cumulative. You can just apply the latest service pack

Answer (score 4):

A service pack is cumulative which means it contains all the SPs/CUs from the past.
An useful link is this one : [sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/)
This will give you a full list of all SPs/CUs to see what you have to install to be up to date.

To patch your server always:

1. Apply the most recent service pack
2. Apply the most recent CU from that service pack

Looking at the SQL 2012, if you want the most recent up-to-date version you'll have to install SP4, and then the latest CU, 11.0.7469.6